# How to solve the problem, that the scale of variables influence the gradient/optimization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-regression, scales, gradient-descent

I've the problem that, using something related to Fisher-scoring, the gradient, which is usually the sum over a variable times a value which depends upon the parameter we are looking for, the updates will mainly focus on the elements whose scales are large.

**Example:**

If I use some spline to estimate the impact on a dependent variable in a smooth fashion, the scale of the spline-columns will be very small compared to a parametric impact of a variable which is time (measured in days) or price (measured in hundreds).

**My question is**:

Should I use some sort of standardization of variables before optimization to adjust for the difference in scale or should I rather, using something like the `optim()` function in R, provide a scaling-factor within the optimization procedure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are using steepest descent. It is standard practice to scale the variables by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation before using the algorithm. 
You can also use a tuning parameter (learning rate) to control the rate of descent.

Usually, the algorithm will have trouble converging on a parameter if the scale of the variable associated with that parameter is too large. You can find information about this in many of the online machine learning courses (The Stanford machine learning course by Andrew Ng on Coursera is a good one- He has a video called Gradient Descent in Practice) or in Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie and Tibshirani.

Comment: But will the parameters interpretation not change from the change in unit to the change in standard deviations?

Comment: Yes, it will change. Is there a reason you're not using Newton-Raphson?

Comment: Currently I was using nlminb in expectation it will perform a Quasi-Newton like Algorithm (for instance BFGS). Probably it did but the values it returned indicated, by looking at the gradient, by default no scaling is applied (for instance by eigenvalues). Using optim, with method="BFGS", in the contrary to the latter method does return values which are quite similar but with a more meaningful gradient. So I presume the BFGS-Routine, implemented withim the optim package, does the scaling which I was looking for?

Comment: BFGS uses an approximation of the information, and it is scaling using that. Newton-Raphson scales using the information. In these cases, the gradient is multiplied by the inverse of the information (or an approximation to it).

Comment: My problem is, I did not mention that before, that using different approaches, my information is probably not well conditioned and hence not invertible. So in this case it would make more sense to use BFGS right? As far as I know, the Newton-Raphson uses the Hessian itself and BFGS approximates the Hessian such that it is not so computational expensive and invertible right?